# BufferBlock and TPL dataflow behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I've got some questions about Bufferblock and Dataflow processing in
general. Suppose I have a set up something like the following (I
copied this code from another question, but it serves to illustrate)

```
var forwarder = new BufferBlock<SomeType>();
forwarder.LinkTo(target1, item => matchesTarget1(item));
forwarder.LinkTo(target2, item => matchesTarget2(item));
forwarder.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<SomeType>());
```

Q1. Assuming no concurrency settings, if I add 1000 items which match
Target1 to the forwarder, are they all instantly posted to target1?
i.e. Does the queuing occur within target1, and so the forwarder (BufferBlock) is now empty? I believe yes, which means that the buffer instantly empties itself? Or does target1 refuse things when it decides it can't cope with any more?

Q2. Assuming I set maxdegreeofparallelism of target1 to, say, 4, I
believe this will mean that things will stay in the buffer until the
target is capable of processing them. But does that mean that, if my
queue looked like this, for example:

target1Item

target1Item

target1Item

target1Item

target1Item

target2Item

target2Item

target2Item

Then target2 would not be offered anything to do at all until all 5
target1Items had been accepted. If target1 is a slow process, that
means that target2 may sit around doing nothing when it could be
making itself useful.

I've read and read about this, but I can't find anything which
definitively answers this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a1. That depends on the Bounded Capacity of the target block. The default is -1 (unbounded), so yes, the buffer will empty itself and move all items to target1. If it had a capacity set, and it was reached then the rest of the items would have stayed in the buffer.

a2. AFAIK If we assume that the targets' capacities are unbounded, then all the items will move from the buffer to the target1 and target2. Setting the maxdegreeofparallelism on target1 only allows multiple items to be processed in parallel.

Comment: Right. So all target blocks have an internal queue, then? And BoundedCapacity determines the size of that queue, while maxdegreeofparalellism simply controls how many it will attempt to process at once?

Comment: @user1158174 pretty much. yes.